# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function Pac-man style game

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, pacman

I'm quite new to Javascript and while developing a small Pac-man style game.
I got stuck with this error, unsure what is wrong. Please let me know!

[image: PICTURE 1 Error seen in console]
[image: PICTURE 2 Error pic in Source]

Code here:

```
...(CSS CODE)...

<script type="text/javascript">

var world =[
[1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,2,2,1],
[1,2,1,2,1],
[1,2,2,2,1],
[1,1,1,1,1] 
]

 var worldDict ={
    0:'blank',
    1:'wall',
    2:'sushi'
 }

  function drawWorld(){
   output=" ";

for( var row= 0; row<world.length;row++){
    output+= "<div class = 'row'></div>";
    for ( var x= 0; x<world[row].length;x++){
        console.log("Element: ", worldDict[world[row][x]]);
    }
}
document.getElementbyId('world').innerHTML=output;
```

Comment: `getElementbyId` Capitalization often matters in programming

Comment: `B` is capital letter in `document.getElementById`

Comment: Nice work including all relevant information in your question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should capitalize By in you code. Like this:

```
document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
```

the `Java script` functions are `camel case`

Comment: This is not only wrong, but typo questions should be closed, not answered

Comment: Sorry by Bad, new here

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in above code that correct in bellow javascript code.

```
 <html>
        <head>
        <div id="world"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var world =[
        [1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,2,2,1],
        [1,2,1,2,1],
        [1,2,2,2,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1] 
        ]
        var worldDict ={
            0:'blank',
            1:'wall',
            2:'sushi'
         }
        function drawWorld(){
           output=" ";

        for( var row= 0; row<world.length; row++){

            for ( var x= 0; x<world[row].length; x++){
               output+= "<div class = 'row'> " + worldDict[world[row][x]] + "</div>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
        }
        drawWorld();
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```